# Serial Port Data Received only working when breakpoint set C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read data from serial port. It reads data when I set breakpoint.

I have tried with parent delegate invoke, some delay also. It doesn't work for me.

Here is my code

Read code from class file:

```
        public void comport_DataReceived2(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
            var buffer = new byte[bytes];
            string  test2 = comport.ReadExisting();
            if (IsReadPDSS)
            {
              if(test2 != string.Empty && test2 != " " && test2.Length > 30)
                {
                    test2 = test2.Substring(30);
                    test2.Replace("000000000000P0000W", "");
                    strReceived += test2;
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                strReceived = test2;
            }
        }
```

windows form retriving read data :

string ss=FormObj.strReceived.ToString();

Comment: Your ``test2.Length > 30`` part in the if clause might explain that you get different results when using breakpoints. With debugging you likely collect more "existing" data compared to running at full speed. Hence, your if clause is true during debugging but not when running normally as you would get this event before 30 characters have arrived. Change it to "bytes > 30" if you look for that amount and move the ``comport.ReadExisting()`` call inside the if along with removing the other clauses in the if statement refering to test2.

Comment: hi , very very thanks . it's working .Thanks for your timely help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do application debugging, your system is not entirely frozen. Only the application you debug. Thus, while your app is in a breakpoint, incoming data on the serial port still is being accumulated.

The control flow is a bit fuzzy (probably because you changed it over a few times while looking for the problem). As it is written now, you read the data from the serial port whenever the event is raised. It is not likely that 30 bytes have arrived at the time you read the data. If you break into the debugger and do single stepping, it is rather more likely that you will find more than 30 bytes in the receive buffer (depending on what your device which transmits does).

Hence, a better way to write the control flow would look like this:

```
public void comport_DataReceived2(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
    if( bytes > 30 )
    {
         var test2 = comport.ReadExisting();
        // additional testing code as required...
    }
}
```

Depending on how the event raising behavior works, you might need to accumulate the data yourself in an extra buffer if the event is not getting re-raised after being fired for the first time... But that should be easy enough to test and adapt.